# How to query the expiration time of Facebook access-token?

Tags: facebook, token

I need to know the expiration time of Facebook access-tokens.

I already know the following ways:

1. extend the token life time. The response will contains the token expiration time. But this method require application secret which we do not always have.
2. use the Facebook token debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). But this requires our code to parse this html file and seems not quite elegant.

So is there any possible to use graph api/fql to query the expiration-time of a token?
I've searched on google but got no answer.

Comment: "But this method require application secret which we do not always have." --- how is it possible? If it is your application - you always have the app secret

Comment: So you have Access-Tokens but no App Secret... how come?

Comment: When you get the access token you also get the expiration time, ALWAYS, with the exception of the application token. So just save that *expire* parameter along side the access token and you'll know when it expires.

Comment: @zerkms Our software gets token from other applications. So those applications may not provide the companion expiration time they got when they obtained the token. And they do not provide application secret to us.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh these are not our own applications...

Comment: So they are sharing the customer's Access Tokens... how very Ethical of them... Sry but I have no idea how to do it in that case.

Comment: @NitzanTomer We obtain token from other applications and serve them. These applications just give tokens to us.. So I need to know, if these are simple ways to know the expiration time of a token.

Comment: @shunting: 1. ask the expiration from app owner 2. just perform the query having access token and check if response is correct

Comment: As @zerkms wrote, those are basically your two options, the api does not have an endpoint for that.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll give up to try to use 'graph api'/fql to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the following endpoint and inspect the response:

```
graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
             input_token={token-to-inspect}
             &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
```

if admin token is bad, fb returns

`{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}`

if input_token is bad, fb returns

`{"data":{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","code":190},"is_valid":false}}`

```
    /* successful response
     * {
            "data": {
            "app_id": APPID,
            "is_valid": true,
            "application": "APPNAME",
            "user_id": UID,
            "issued_at": 1371671725,
            "expires_at": 0,
            "scopes": ["create_note", "manage_pages", "photo_upload", "publish_actions", "publish_stream", "share_item", "status_update", "video_upload"]
            }
        }
     */
```